# Bootstrap 3 - Row Fixed Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I am strugling **with Bootstrap 3 grid system.**
Let me explain what I have implemented, what I need and what I did (fail attempt) to achieve.

[image: I have this site with the following Layout]

This is the Layout (HTML | Razor) of the image. For you to have a live version of this [This is the site link](http://www.tugrieta.com/Grieta/tnt-sports/Visitante/Test) to this screen so you can see it and play.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 nopadding">
            <div id="showcaseSection" class="showcaseSection superVideo">
                <ul class="media-list" id="showcaseMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments"></ul>
            </div>


        <div class="hidden-xs">
            <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding">
                <p class="text-center no-margin" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <span>Equipo: @Model.Team1Name (<span id="team1Total">0</span>)</span>
                </p>
                <ul class="media-list team1ListShowCase" id="@Model.Team1Id" data-img="@Url.Action("GetLinkToImageTeam", "Home", new {Id = Model.Team1Id})" data-media="media-left" data-team="@Model.Team1Name" data-class="team1"></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding">
                <p class="text-center no-margin" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <span>Equipo: @Model.Team2Name (<span id="team2Total">0</span>)</span>
                </p>
                <ul class="media-list team2ListShowCase" id="@Model.Team2Id" data-img="@Url.Action("GetLinkToImageTeam", "Home", new {Id = Model.Team2Id})" data-media="media-right" data-team="@Model.Team2Name" data-class="team2"></ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 nopadding">

    <div id="chatcontainer">
        <ul class="media-list" id="chatbody" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments"></ul>

        <div id="chatOptions" class="collapse">
            <p class="text-center">@Model.Title</p>
            <button id="exitroom" class="btn btn-danger" title="Salir" disabled="disabled">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> @Resources.Salir
            </button>
            <span>
                <input type="checkbox" id="isAutoscroll" name="my-checkbox" checked>
                <label>Actualizar Mensajes</label>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (!Model.IsReadOnly)
    {
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="hidden" style="display: none" class="form-control" aria-required="false" readonly id="inresponseto">
            <textarea type="text" rows="2" class="form-control" required="required" aria-required="true" maxlength="500" placeholder="Comentario..." disabled="disabled" id="responseText"></textarea>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="height: 25px;" aria-required="false" readonly id="inresponsetomessage">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="sendresponse" type="button" title="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" title="Opciones" data-target="#chatOptions">
                    <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

**As you can see everything is in one row.** 
I want to have the **Video Section fixed on top** and the **TEXT AREA to comment fixed BOTTOM when on XS (viewports).**

I tried adding this to the row, but I fix the video but I cannot see the TEXT AREA

```
.fixed2 {
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
width: 100%;}
```

I don't know what else to do to show fixed top (video) and botton fixed (Chat Textbox) and scrollable comments in the middle when in XS.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the height for `#chatcontainer` for tablet/mobile will fix the issue. Example:

```
@media(max-width: 767px) {  
  #chatcontainer{
    height: calc(50vh - 80px);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Vishnu, If I could give you 500 points I would do it. Thank you so much for his super easy fix.

Comment: @MRFerocius I'm happy that I was able to resolve your problem. That's more satisfactory than gaining points/reputations. :-)